# Does a day off for work related paperwork count as vacation?

Tags: vacation, law, leave

I'll need a day off to prepare my work permit. Does it count as work or a vacation?

edit: I'm in a consulting company in France

Comment: Ask your manager. This would vary by company or even manager

Comment: If you fulfill this paperwork, does it allow you to work for anyone, or just the company in question?

Comment: just the company in question

Comment: When I worked abroad (years ago now), my employer arranged personal appointments at the necessary offices to process my residence permit. That way I didn't have to wait for hours, and it made the "processing" pretty much just stamping my passport since it was clear my employment was real..

Answer (score 2):

> I'll need a day off to prepare my work permit. Does it count as work or a vacation?

It depends:

When voluntary changing employers and starting in a new job, any time you need to invest before you land that job and can actually start your first day in the new job, is usually your own.

Frequently new employers will reimburse (some of) the expenses required to secure your new job (things like travel expenses, other (mandatory) fees, tickets and hotels) but I have never heard a company proposing that they will pay you for *time* you spent (either on interviews or other administrative tasks, such as obtaining a visa) 
 before you can start on your new job. I'm certainly not aware of any legal requirement to do so.

Sometimes when your new job involves relocation to an altogether different country, you'll get a relocation package and some paid leave to prepare for that, but your time investment usually gets paid for by  starting your contract on an earlier date before the date you're actually  expected to make your first appearance in the office.

When you need to travel for your current job and your employer requires that of you, in other words you need to make **a business trip** or get transferred abroad, and that business trip takes you to a foreign country that requires travel visa and work permits, obtaining those are work related tasks which you should not have to do in your own free time.

Be aware that you may not have to do all the work yourself for such foreign trips either. Often companies hire a corporate travel or relocation agency that also provides additional services which may include  visa assistance. Possibly the agency can request and obtain the necessary visa on your behalf or at least help to make the process more efficient.